# Idiom to describe when someone has no telephone

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

Imagine that somebody has no telephone. I actually mean a man who has for example 5 telephones but has not paid bils for them.

Is there any idiom to say something about "he is cut from the world" then?

Comment: You mean like a junkie who's finally kicked his addiction and achieved serenity without his drug of choice, right? Phone addiction is a serious disorder.

Comment: I think OP would like, “he is ***cut off*** from the world.”

Comment: Yes, “he is cut off from the world.” sounds best for me. I actually mean a man who has for example 5 telephones but has not paid bils for them.

Comment: "disconnected from society" ...  might be a bit too close to a pun, but might work for someone poor.. if it was on purpose the "off the grid" answer fits well

Comment: Something like "out of touch," "out of contact," "out of reach?"

Answer (score 3):

Idiomatically, one could say "**he is off the grid**", generally meaning independence from public utilities. Primarily it refers to someone not reliant on public electricity, but can also mean cut off from cell coverage, or a telephone landline, or generally un-contactable, or even un-locatable.

Reference: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/off+the+grid

Comment: This is a good answer for someone who has chosen not to own a working phone as a matter of principal.  It doesn't do as good a job as catching the spirit of someone destitute, homeless, perhaps afflicted by mental illness etc.

Comment: @Tom22: I somewhat agree with your point, but "off the grid" doesn't inherently state the _cause_ either way, it only focuses on the effect. It doesn't specify whether being "off the grid" came about through choice, preference, punitive measure or inescapable situation.

Answer (score 0):

A Luddite. I am that person, cut out Telephones 30 years ago and never had a mobile. Praise be to peace and tranquility.

Comment: That doesn't seem to apply to a person who has five telephones and doesn't pay the bills.

Comment: Also doesn't seem to apply to someone posting on EL&U.

Comment: Welcome to SE EL&U. Please take the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the help section on [answering questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Here we're looking for answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed. (I'm almost certain yours will unless you edit it.)